# How to skip rest of arguments if specific add_argument is selected using argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, argparse

```
try:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Note: -un is not mandatory',
            usage='use "python %(prog)s -h" for help\nNote: *** Astericks represent mandatory fields',
            formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('-re',
                        '--regard',
                        required=True,
                        # choices=['Prod', 'Dev', 'Test'],
                        type=str,
                        help='* Rancher Environment Pass')
    parser.add_argument('-g',
                        '--group_names',
                        # required=False,
                        type=str,
                        help='* Group Name(s) - Specify the group names using comma separated values (no spaces permitted) - ex: group1, group2, group3')
    parser.add_argument('-un',
                        '--user_names',
                        type=str,
                        help='Username(s) - Specify the group names using comma separated values (no spaces permitted) - ex: user1, user2, user3')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    sys.exit()
except:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Note: -un is not mandatory',
            usage='use "python %(prog)s -h" for help\nNote: *** Astericks represent mandatory fields',
            formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('-u',
                        '--env',
                        required=True,
                        choices=['Prod', 'Dev', 'Test'],
                        help='* Rancher Environment --> Prod/Dev/Test')
    parser.add_argument('-b',
                        '--business_unit',
                        required=True,
                        type=str,
                        help='* The Business Unit you choose to use --> "PFE Business Unit, ex: FBO, R&D, PGS, PCH"')
    parser.add_argument('-p',
                        '--project_name',
                        required=True,
                        type=str,
                        help='* The Project Name you choose to use --> Project Name')
    parser.add_argument('-e',
                        '--app_environment_name',
                        required=True,
                        type=str,
                        help='* The Application Environment Name you choose to use --> Application Environment, ex Prod, Dev, DR, Test, Staging')
    parser.add_argument('-g',
                        '--group_names',
                        required=True,
                        type=str,
                        help='* Group Name(s) - Specify the group names using comma separated values (no spaces permitted) - ex: group1, group2, group3')
    parser.add_argument('-un',
                        '--user_names',
                        type=str,
                        help='Username(s) - Specify the group names using comma separated values (no spaces permitted) - ex: user1, user2, user3')
    parser.add_argument('-s',
                        '--app_sc_id',
                        required=True,
                        type=str,
                        help='* Please specify App_SC_ID')
    parser.add_argument('-d',
                        '--description',
                        required=True,
                        type=str,
                        help='* Please specify a brief description in quotes - ex: "My Brief Description"')

    args = parser.parse_args()

# # re_pass()
if args.regard:
    pass
    #program goes here

    ##################
    sys.exit()
else:
    re_pass()
```

Comment: This kind of unrestricted `try/except` is dangerous, potentially hiding all sorts of unintended errors.

Comment: Your question and parsing intent is not clear.  Looks a bit like you are trying to parse the input in one way, and if that fails, parse another way.  That's not a good approach.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want it to do, but it might be something you can achieve with argparse's existing features: sub-commands, partial-parsing, or conflicting-options. Here is the argparse documentation where you can find all those: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html